# How to make aggregated CSV file column unaggregated in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

A CSV file that contains the aggregated value of power consumption. It contains the total value up to date but I need to use the instantaneous power. It is in form of power consumption at every 5-minute interval. Like it is in form of,

| Power |
| --- |
| 1300 |
| 1300 |
| 1302 |
| 1303 |
| 1303 |
| 1305 |
| 1305 |
| 1305 |

I am willing to convert it to an unaggregated instantenous form like:

| Power |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 0 |
| 0 |

How do I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1300, 1300,1302,1303,1303,1305,1305,1305])
df.diff().fillna(0)
```

[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) used to replace leading NaN with zero.